Smart Card SMIME Sign/Encrypt Error with ThunderBird on Ubuntu

When I try to send Sign or Encrypted Email from Thunderbird on Ubuntu, above error appeared. It seems that Thunderbird was unable to a access private key or Certificate?
All Other steps was completed successfully, adding Smart-card device and import CA certificates etc.

I am using Smartcat-HSM, all above steps have been followed, smartcard is listed and certificates are loaded and shown in thunderbird.
But issue is when I Write an email and then sign or encrypt it. TB is unable to access private key and shows above error.
I have also done one more test, i used the same certificates in soft form(pem) then i was able to send email with Digitally signed and encrypted. After that i removed that soft/pem imported certificate and use smartcard of the same certificate/user, but it failed to decrypt the previously sent message to itself. Also not able to send encrypted/signed emails with same above error. It seems TB is unable to access private key from smart card.

What versions of Ubuntu and Thunderbird?
What smartcard?
Under TB edit->settings->Privacy & Security->Certificates what is under "Manage Certificates..."?
What do you see under "Security Devices..."?
It should show NSS stuff. To get to a smartcard you may need to "Load" the path to some PKCS11 module for example OpenSC. If OpenSC is installed the path to the PKCS11 module would look something like:
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
If everything above is working, you should be able to see the smartcard reader at least, and see the certificates.

If you are using Ubuntu 24.04  https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-24-04-released/ says: "Thunderbird is now distributed as a Snap package" The problem maybe related to  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1967632  Snap does not handle smartcards which use PCSC.  22.04 Thunderbird did noy use SNAP.   Circumvention may be to use Mozilla versions of FireFox and Thunderbird which do not use SNAP.  See: https://www.mozilla.org/  and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/well-known-sources-for-downloading-thunderbird
